# ClassCastException: ArrayList cannot be cast to String

Tags: java, string, casting, arraylist

I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String

This is the code:

```
public static List<String>produit_cart(ArrayList l)
{   
    List<String>re=new ArrayList();
    List<String>l4=new ArrayList();

    re=(List<String>) l.get(0);

    for(int i=1;i<l.size();i++)
    {
        l4=new ArrayList();

        for(int j=0;j<re.size();j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<((ArrayList)l.get(i)).size();k++)
            {
                l4.add(re.get(j) +
                        " " +
                        (String)((ArrayList)l.get(i)).get(k));

            }   
        }

        re=new ArrayList();
        for(int m=0;m<l4.size();m++)
        {
            re.add(l4.get(m));
        }   
    }

    return re;
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
l4.add(re.get(j)+" "+(String)((ArrayList)l.get(i)).get(k));
```

I tried to rewrite it as:

```
l4.add(re.get(j)+" "+((ArrayList)l.get(i)).get(k));
```

but it didn't work. What should I do ?

Comment: Why are you not using generics on both sides of your declarations? Why are your variable names non-helpful?

Comment: The 2nd "try" won't cause that exception...

Comment: You need to functionally decompose this. Name things in an orthogonal fashion (as mentioned above), put some comments in where things aren't obvious and be consistent with your usage of generics. At the moment, three loops deep, this code just makes no sense. If you make it readable, the answer WILL jump out at you.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Hovercraft & Jeff... This code is a mess!  If you just re-write it with an attempt to make it readable, your errors will become obvious.  I've probably mis-read your code a half-dozen times trying to compose an answer... That's a bad sign for code that _SHOULD_ be very simple.

Answer (score 13):

You have a problem with your parentheses.

You want to call `get(i)` and `get(k)` on your `ArrayList`, then cast that to a `String`.

Your code casts the result of `l.get(i)` to a `String`, then tries to call `get(k)` on it.

... Actually, I can barely determine what your code does, because it is so difficult to read in its current state.

The following should work and also make your code much easier to follow:

```
ArrayList tempList = (ArrayList) l.get(i);
String tail = (String) tempList.get(k);
l4.add(re.get(j) + " " + tail;
```

One thing that would **really** help would be to ensure that list `l` is a `list of string lists`.  Then you wouldn't have to cast at all.  You could achive that by using the following declaration (if at all possible):

```
List<ArrayList<String>> listL = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

---

Here are some suggestions of how you could re-write the above and make it much easier to follow:

```
public static List<String> produitCart(List<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists)
{   
    List<String> returnList = listOfLists.get(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < listOfLists.size(); i++) {

        List<String> listFour = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int j = 0; j < returnList.size(); j++) {
            ArrayList<String> tempList = listOfLists.get(i);
            for (int k = 0; k < tempList.size(); k++) {
                listFour.add(returnList.get(j) + " " + tempList.get(k));
            }   
        }

        returnList = new ArrayList();

        for (int m = 0; m < listFour.size(); m++) {
            returnList.add(listFour.get(m));
        }   
    }

    return returnList;
}
```