# How to avoid casting error 'ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String'

Tags: java, list, arraylist, nested

What i am stuck in getting arguments of List files and making it readable, but before that removing the extra characters from the name of the file using .replace function.

```
List<String> files = (List<String>) getArguments().getSerializable("file");
    assert files != null;
        fileName = files.get(0);//String fileName
        fileName = fileName.replace("[", "");
        fileName = fileName.replace("]", "");
    remotePDFViewPager = new RemotePDFViewPager(getActivity(),
            APIClient.FILE_URL + fileName, this);
    pdfViewLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972860/classcastexception-arraylist-cannot-be-cast-to-string

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ArrayList<String>> filesArray =
   (List<ArrayList<String>>) getArguments().getSerializable("file");
ArrayList<String> nestedFile = filesArray.get(0);
```